# Android Error on passing data from one activity to another acitvity

Tags: android

I am creating an app which calculates the total marks & percentage and shows the result in the next activity called ResultActvity. I am using same ResultActivity for showing result for 1st yr student & 2nd yr student marks, everything works fine when it come to show the result for 1st yr students but when it comes to show the result for second yr students it is only showing total marks but no % is shown. I am a newbie to android development please help me in fixing this. Thank You :).

**FIRSTACTIVITY**

```
    package com.jntuhcalculator.anu.jntuhcalculator;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Typeface;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        /**
         * Created by anu on 18/9/15.
         */
        public class FirstMarks extends Activity {

            TextView tv_Subjects1, tv_Internal1, tv_External1;
            EditText et_Int_Eng, et_Int_M1, et_Int_MM, et_Int_Phy, et_Int_Chem, et_Int_Cp, et_Int_ElcsLab, et_Int_EpLab, et_Int_ItLab, et_Int_Draw;
            EditText et_Ext_Eng, et_Ext_M1, et_Ext_MM, et_Ext_Phy, et_Ext_Chem, et_Ext_Cp, et_Ext_ElcsLab, et_Ext_EpLab, et_Ext_ItLab, et_Ext_Draw;
            Button btn_Cal1, btn_Ok1;
            int IEng,IM1,IMM,IEPhy,IEChem,ICp,IEDraw,IELCS_Lab,IEP_LAB,IIT_LAB;
            int EEng,EM1,EMM,EEPhy,EEChem,ECp,EEDraw,EELCS_Lab,EEP_LAB,EIT_LAB;
            int ITotal1,ETotal1,Total1;
            float Percentage1;
            String f1;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.marks_1);


                //INITIALISING VIEWS.
                //INITIALISING TEXT VIEWS.
                tv_Subjects1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Subject1);
                tv_Internal1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Internal1);
                tv_External1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_External1);
                //INITIALISING EDIT TEXT.
                //INTERNAL
                et_Int_Eng = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_Eng);
                et_Int_M1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_M1);
                et_Int_MM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_MM);
                et_Int_Phy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_Phy);
                et_Int_Chem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_Chem);
                et_Int_Cp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_Cp);
                et_Int_ElcsLab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_ElcsLab);
                et_Int_EpLab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_EpLab);
                et_Int_ItLab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_ItLab);
                et_Int_Draw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_Draw);
                //EXTERNAL
                et_Ext_Eng = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_Eng);
                et_Ext_M1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_M1);
                et_Ext_MM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_MM);
                et_Ext_Phy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_Phy);
                et_Ext_Chem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_Chem);
                et_Ext_Cp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_Cp);
                et_Ext_ElcsLab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_ElcsLab);
                et_Ext_EpLab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_EpLab);
                et_Ext_ItLab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_ItLab);
                et_Ext_Draw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_Draw);
                //INITIALISING BUTTON
                btn_Cal1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Cal1);
                btn_Ok1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Ok1);




                //WHEN SAVE BUTTON IS CLICKED.
                btn_Ok1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                      //GETTING VALUES FROM EDIT TEXT.
                        //INTERNALS.
                        IEng = getIntValue(et_Int_Eng);
                        IM1 = getIntValue(et_Int_M1);
                        IMM = getIntValue(et_Int_MM);
                        IEPhy = getIntValue(et_Int_Phy);
                        IEChem = getIntValue(et_Int_Chem);
                        ICp = getIntValue(et_Int_Cp);
                        IEDraw = getIntValue(et_Int_Draw);
                        IELCS_Lab = getIntValue(et_Int_ElcsLab);
                        IEP_LAB = getIntValue(et_Int_EpLab);
                        //EXTERNALS.
                        EEng = getIntValue(et_Ext_Eng);
                        EM1 = getIntValue(et_Ext_M1);
                        EMM = getIntValue(et_Ext_MM);
                        EEPhy = getIntValue(et_Ext_Phy);
                        EEChem = getIntValue(et_Ext_Chem);
                        ECp = getIntValue(et_Ext_Cp);
                        EEDraw = getIntValue(et_Ext_Draw);
                        EELCS_Lab = getIntValue(et_Ext_ElcsLab);
                        EEP_LAB = getIntValue(et_Ext_EpLab);
                        EIT_LAB = getIntValue(et_Ext_ItLab);

                     //CALCUATIONS.
                        //INTERNAL TOTAL.
                        ITotal1 = (IEng+IM1+IMM+IEPhy+IEChem+ICp+IEDraw+IELCS_Lab+IEP_LAB+IIT_LAB);
                        //EXTERNAL TOTAL.
                        ETotal1 = (EEng+EM1+EMM+EEPhy+EEChem+ECp+EEDraw+EELCS_Lab+EEP_LAB+EIT_LAB);
                        //TOTAL.
                        Total1 = (ITotal1+ETotal1);
                        //PERCENTAGE.
                        Percentage1 = (float)(Total1/10);
                        f1 = Float.toString(Percentage1);

                        //CREATING TOAST.
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Press Result",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                btn_Cal1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(FirstMarks.this,FirstResult.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("res1",Total1);
                        b.putString("per1",f1);
                        i.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                });




            }



            //SUB-FUNCTION FOR GETTING INTEGER FROM EDITTEXT.
            private int getIntValue(EditText et) throws NumberFormatException {
                int i =0;
                String s;
                try {
                    s = et.getText().toString();
                    if(s.equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Marks",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    i = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    return i;

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR:", "NOT A NUMBER");
                }
                  return 0;

            }


          }
```

```
**SECONDACTIVITY**
```

```
    package com.jntuhcalculator.anu.jntuhcalculator;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Typeface;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        /**
         * Created by anu on 19/9/15.
         */
        public class SecondMarks_1 extends Activity {

            TextView tv_PS,tv_MFCS,tv_DS,tv_DLD,tv_EDC,tv_BEE,tv_EELab,tv_DSLab;
            TextView tv_Subjects21, tv_Internal21, tv_External21;
            EditText et_Int_PS, et_Int_MFCS, et_Int_DS, et_Int_DLD, et_Int_EDC, et_Int_BEE, et_Int_EELab, et_Int_DSLab;
            EditText et_Ext_PS, et_Ext_MFCS, et_Ext_DS, et_Ext_DLD, et_Ext_EDC, et_Ext_BEE, et_Ext_EELab, et_Ext_DSLab;
            Button btn_Cal21, btn_Ok21;
            int IPS,IMFCS,IDS,IDLD,IEDC,IBEE,IEE_Lab,IDS_Lab;
            int EPS,EMFCS,EDS,EDLD,EEDC,EBEE,EEE_Lab,EDS_Lab;
            int ITotal21,ETotal21,Total21;
            float Percentage21;
            String f21;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.secondmarks_1);


                //INITIALISING VIEWS.
                //INITIALISING TEXT VIEWS.
                tv_Subjects21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Subject21);
                tv_Internal21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Internal21);
                tv_External21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_External21);
                //SUBJECT TEXT VIEWS.
                tv_PS = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv_PS));
                tv_MFCS = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv_MFCS));
                tv_DS = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv_DS));
                tv_DLD = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv_DLD));
                tv_EDC = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv_EDC));
                tv_BEE = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv_BEE));
                tv_EELab = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv_EE_Lab));
                tv_DSLab = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.tv_DS_Lab));
                //INITIALISING EDIT TEXT.
                //INTERNAL
                et_Int_PS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_PS);
                et_Int_MFCS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_MFCS);
                et_Int_DS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_DS);
                et_Int_DLD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_DLD);
                et_Int_EDC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_EDC);
                et_Int_BEE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_BEE);
                et_Int_EELab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_EELab);
                et_Int_DSLab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Int_DSLab);
                //EXTERNAL
                et_Ext_PS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_PS);
                et_Ext_MFCS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_MFCS);
                et_Ext_DS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_DS);
                et_Ext_DLD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_DLD);
                et_Ext_EDC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_EDC);
                et_Ext_BEE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_BEE);
                et_Ext_EELab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_EELab);
                et_Ext_DSLab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ext_DSLab);
                //INITIALISING BUTTON
                btn_Cal21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Cal21);
                btn_Ok21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Ok21);
        //DISPLAYING SUBJECT NAMES WHEN TEXT VIEW IS CLICKED.
                tv_PS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        disp(tv_PS, "PS:Probabilty & Statistics");
                    }
                });
                tv_MFCS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        disp(tv_MFCS, "MFCS:Mathematical Foundation Of Computer Science");

                    }
                });
                tv_DS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {disp(tv_DS, "DS:Data Structures");
                    }
                });
                tv_DLD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        disp(tv_DLD, "DLD:Digital Logic Design");
                    }
                });
                tv_EDC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        disp(tv_EDC, "EDC:Electronic Devices & Circuits");
                    }
                });
                tv_BEE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) { disp(tv_BEE, "BEE:Basic Electrical Engineering");
                    }
                });
                tv_EELab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) { disp(tv_EELab, "Electrical & Electronics Lab");
                    }
                });
                tv_DSLab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {disp(tv_DSLab, "Data Structures Lab");
                    }
                });


                //WHEN SAVE BUTTON IS CLICKED.
                btn_Ok21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //GETTING VALUES FROM EDIT TEXT.
                        //INTERNALS.
                        IPS = getIntValue(et_Int_PS);
                        IMFCS = getIntValue(et_Int_MFCS);
                        IDS = getIntValue(et_Int_DS);
                        IDLD = getIntValue(et_Int_DLD);
                        IEDC = getIntValue(et_Int_EDC);
                        IBEE = getIntValue(et_Int_BEE);
                        IEE_Lab = getIntValue(et_Int_EELab);
                        IDS_Lab = getIntValue(et_Int_DSLab);
                        //EXTERNALS.
                        EPS = getIntValue(et_Ext_PS);
                        EMFCS = getIntValue(et_Ext_MFCS);
                        EDS = getIntValue(et_Ext_DS);
                        EDLD = getIntValue(et_Ext_DLD);
                        EEDC = getIntValue(et_Ext_EDC);
                        EBEE = getIntValue(et_Ext_BEE);
                        EEE_Lab = getIntValue(et_Ext_EELab);
                        EDS_Lab = getIntValue(et_Ext_DSLab);

                        //CALCULATIONS.
                        //INTERNAL TOTAL.
                        ITotal21 = (IPS+IMFCS+IDS+IDLD+IEDC+IBEE+IEE_Lab+IDS_Lab);
                        //EXTERNAL TOTAL.
                        ETotal21 = (EPS+EMFCS+EDS+EDLD+EEDC+EBEE+EEE_Lab+EDS_Lab);
                        //TOTAL.
                        Total21 = (ITotal21+ETotal21);
                        //PERCENTAGE.
                        Percentage21 = ((Total21/750)*100);
                        f21 = Float.toString(Percentage21);

                        //CREATING TOAST.
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Press Result",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                  btn_Cal21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SecondMarks_1.this,FirstResult.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("res1",Total21);
                        b.putString("per1",f21);
                        i.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                });




            }



            //SUB-FUNCTION FOR GETTING INTEGER FROM EDITTEXT.
            private int getIntValue(EditText et) throws NumberFormatException {
                int i =0;
                String s;
                try {
                    s = et.getText().toString();
                    if(s.equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Marks",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    i = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    return i;

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR:", "NOT A NUMBER");
                }
                return 0;

            }

            private void disp(TextView tv,String s){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

```
**RESULTACTIVITY**
<pre><code>

    package com.jntuhcalculator.anu.jntuhcalculator;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    /**
     * Created by anu on 18/9/15.
     */
    public class FirstResult extends Activity {

        EditText et_Total1,et_Percentage1;
        Button btn_Exit1;
        int sres1;
        String sper1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.result_first);

            //INITIALISING VIEWS.
            et_Total1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Total1);
            et_Percentage1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Percentage1);
            btn_Exit1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Exit1);

            //GETTING DATA FROM PREVIOUS ACTIVITY.
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
             sres1 = b.getInt("res1", 0);
             sper1 = b.getString("per1");

           //Converting Float Into String.
            //f = Float.toString(sper1);

            //SETTING RESULTS.
            et_Total1.setText(sres1+"");
            et_Percentage1.setText(sper1+"%");

            //WHEN EXIT IS CLICKED.
            btn_Exit1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YearDetails.class);
                    i.putExtra("Total",sres1);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
               }
            });


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are properly not able to send values between different activities, i will give you an example, try it.

The syntax is like this

For sending data

```
 String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
 intent.putExtra("keyName","value");
```

For receiving at ActivityTwo

```
String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

Additional hint:-

So you need to edit in FirstActivity

```
 btn_Cal21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SecondMarks_1.this,FirstResult.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("res1",Total21);
                        b.putString("per1",f21);
                        i.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
```

Same for the following activities.

Still Did not get ? Actually in you FirstActivity you have put

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FirstMarks.this,FirstResult.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("res1",Total1);
                        b.putString("per1",f1);
```

And in your second activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(SecondMarks_1.this,FirstResult.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("res1",Total21);
                    b.putString("per1",f21);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
```

You see you have used **per1 string in both places**, change that, that is probably causing the app not to get values(possibly give some other string).

And in this part, you need to add code for 2nd activity result to be received.

```
             Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
             sres1 = b.getInt("res1", 0);
             sper1 = b.getString("per1");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahh yeah But the thing is i have only one activity for displaying result ..!!

Comment: Yea, its ok, just recevie it in receiving activity, kindly upvote answer if it has helped you

Comment: Thanks Alot Buddy..:)